# Cosa significa «dalla cinta in sue»?

Tags: word-meaning

Riproduco per intero un enimma di Tommaso Stigliani (1573-1651) sulle forbici:

> A un tempo stesso io mi son una, e due,
>       E fo due ciò ch'era una primamente.
>       Una mi adopra con le cinque sue
>       Contra infiniti che in capo ha la gente.
>       Tutta son bocca *dalla cinta in sue*,
>       E  più mordo sdentata che con dente.
>       Ho due bellichi a contrapposti siti,
>       Gli occhi ho ne' piedi, e spesso a gli occhi i diti.

Ho marcato in corsivo la parte che suscita dubbi.

Non riesco a capire quella *cinta*. Le forbici sono come una bocca che mangia tutto, capisco solo questo; ma non c'è nessun muro ovvio (per Treccani #1). E gli altri sensi pare siano anche meno rilevanti; certo, non sono ovvi. Non capisco anche che cosa sono «le sue», di chi sono ecc (sempre nel verso #5; quelle «sue» nel verso #3 sono ovvie).

Potreste spiegarmi la frase marcata? Grazie!

Comment: Tieni conto che "enimma" è maschile, quindi l'articolo è "un" e il pronome diretto è "lo". Per quanto riguarda "dalla cinta in sue": "cinta" è la "cintura", la "cintola", insomma qualcosa che cinge la vita (intesa come parte del corpo); "sue" è invece "su". Quindi in quella riga si intende che dalla parte centrale, la più stretta, in su, è "solo bocca".

Comment: @Benedetta Grazie, molto chiaro! Ho trovato secondo le tue indicazioni: http://treccani.it/vocabolario/sue .

Comment: Un'osservazione aggiuntiva: in un testo in versi ben scritto, una parola non può rimare con sé stessa (a parte rare eccezioni come “Cristo” che in Dante compare di proposito in tre rime successive). Quindi se un “sue” è un aggettivo/pronome possessivo, l'altro “sue” doveva in ogni caso essere qualcos'altro.

Comment: @Benedetta, mi sembra che ci sia tutto quello che serve per rispondere (magari puoi aggiungere anche l'eco dantesco di “dalla cintola in su”).

Comment: @DaG: va bene. Anche in questo caso, verifica che tutto vada bene.

Comment: @Wanderer: ho fatto le due correzioni che ti avevo segnalato.

Comment: @Benedetta Grazie anche per le correzioni! Avevo dubbi sulla politica di questo QA, credevo che fossi supposto di evitar la correzione del testo attuale della domanda (per le ragioni quale il contesto della domanda ecc).

Comment: @DaG Sì, sono d'accordo. Ci sono pero modi diversi per definire che cosa è una parola; per esempio, si può definirla come una sequenza di suoni che ha qualsiasi valore ben definito; in questo senso, il poema è errato in ogni caso. Non sono uno specialista della poesia, perciò non saprei dire se questo senso sia appropriato oppure no…

Comment: Hai ragione, @Wanderer, mi sono spiegato male. Intendevo dire che «‘Facile’, e ... in genere evitata, è la rima *identica*, che si verifica quando una parola rima con sé stessa ... . Può invece dar luogo a ricerche sofisticate ... la rima *equivoca*, che si verifica quando rimano tra loro due o più parole foneticamente identiche (omofone), ma diverse per significato e per appartenenza grammaticale»: vedi [qui](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/rima_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) dove c'è anche un bell'esempio di rime equivoche nel Petrarca.

Comment: @DaG Sì, molto elucidante! Ho [trovato](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Canzoniere_(Rerum_vulgarium_fragmenta)/Quand%27io_son_tutto_v%C3%B2lto_in_quella_parte) quel sonetto per intero. Pare che Petrarca abbia ricercato molto le rime equivoci (e identici) nel sonetto, mentre che la rima equivoca *sue* / *sue* sembra forse un po' casuale, nel senso che il poema non sarebbe peggio se Stigliani usasse qualche altra rima… Ma stiamo divertendo la discussione fuori tema. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'espressione, entrata tra i modi di dire dell'italiano, è un'eco del X canto dell'Inferno di Dante («Vedi là Farinata che s'è dritto / da la cintola in sú tutto 'l vedrai»).

"Cinta" è la "cintura", la "cintola" (secondo l'uso di Dante), insomma qualcosa che cinge la vita (intesa come parte del corpo); "sue" è invece "su". Quindi in quella riga si intende che dalla parte centrale, la più stretta, in su, la protagonista dell'enimma è "solo bocca" (le due lame che si aprono e chiudono).